# How to insert value in "Class" when creating Quickbook Invoice in PHP?

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to enter the value in "Class" field when Quickbook Invoices are getting created.
But I am not able to Enter the value for "class" field ( marked in a red ellipse )
[image]

I have tried the following

```
$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();
$Invoice        = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();
$class_value    = "3700000000000449312";
//$class_value    = 3700000000000449312; //also tried

$Invoice->setClassRef($class_value);
```

Please correct me. if I am doing wrong then please share the correct method.

Thanks

Comment: tried going through their API?

Comment: @Akintunde Yes, i am trying through API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing R&D on this I have found the solution.

we can insert value in "Class" like below

```
$class_value            = "3700000000000449312";
$Line                   = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$SalesItemLineDetail    = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setClassRef( $class_value );
$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail( $SalesItemLineDetail );
```

Comment: This answer saved the day. I was trying to attach the ClassRef to the invoice itself, not the line item. This was the correct solution. Thank you for the help.